# Adding getters / setters to prototype

Tags: javascript

In the following piece of code, I am trying to add getters and setters to the prototype.

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.displayCar = displayCar;
}

function displayCar() {
    console.log("A Beautiful " + this.year + " " + this.color + " " + this.make + " " + this.model);
}

var c1 = new Car("Ford", "Mustang", 1969);
var c2 = new Car("Skoda", "Octavia", 1999);

var p = Car.prototype;
Object.defineProperty(p, "color", {
    get: function() {return this.color},
    set: function(c) {this.color = c}
    });

c2.color = "White";

c2.displayCar();
```

Could someone please help me understand why I am getting this error on line 18:

```
 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem's in these lines:

```
var p = Car.prototype;
Object.defineProperty(p, "color", {
    set: function(c) {this.color = c} // Setter
});

c2.color = "White";
```

***Explanation:***

What's going on here is that you are setting c2.color to "White". This trigger's the setter you defined before. This setter sets this.color to "White" again, which calls the setter once again. And so on... until you exceed the stack size.

> So, you're getting stuck in an **infinite recursion** problem.

***How to solve it***

A possible solution to this problem would be to store the value of the "color" property in another property like this:

```
var p = Car.prototype;
Object.defineProperty(p, "color", {
    get: function() {return this.color2},
    set: function(c) {this.color2 = c}
});

c2.color = "White";

c2.color // White!
```

HOPE IT HELPS!! ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think you must use a different name for the internal property (it worked in my testing), perhaps use _color

```
Object.defineProperty(p, "color", {
    get: function() {return this._color},
    set: function(c) {this._color = c}
    });
```

Comment: I like the underscore before the variable name.